# Using CSS or JavaScript to Hide Specific Rows in Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an outline of a table in HTML and I have data being inserted into it through javascript from an online dataset. `Cell 0` is the first column with information. Some of the rows in that column will have a name displayed in `cell 0` and some will have a dash (-) displayed in `cell 0`. I have set a class for `cell0` in my javascript to `hide-dash`. How can I use either CSS or JavaScript to hide ALL TABLE ROWS where `cell0` equals a dash (-)?

JSFiddle example to better understand what I need. I need the dash row hidden:
https://jsfiddle.net/k8jr16j6/

HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-borderless" id="top25">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>MGN $</th>
      <th>MGN %</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var customerTable = document.getElementById("top25");
var tableRow = customerTable.insertRow();
      var cell0 = tableRow.insertCell(0);
      cell0.style.textAlign = "left";
      cell0.innerHTML = row['account filter'];
      cell0.className='hide-dash';

      var cell1 = tableRow.insertCell(1);
      cell1.innerHTML = row['sales'];

      var cell2 = tableRow.insertCell(2);
      cell2.innerHTML = row['margin dollar'];

      var cell3 = tableRow.insertCell(3);
      cell3.innerHTML = row['margin percent'];
```

Comment: Please make a snippet or jsFiddle for see it

Comment: If you want to hide the row, then why are you not setting that class on the row? Right now you are setting it on the cell ...

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman I added a jsfiddle example of what my table looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var customerTable = document.getElementById("top25");
  var tableRow = customerTable.insertRow();
      var cell0 = tableRow.insertCell(0);
      cell0.style.textAlign = "left";
      cell0.innerHTML = row['account filter'];
      cell0.className='hide-dash';
      if (row['account filter'] == "-") tableRow.style.display="none";

      var cell1 = tableRow.insertCell(1);
      cell1.innerHTML = row['sales'];

      var cell2 = tableRow.insertCell(2);
      cell2.innerHTML = row['margin dollar'];

      var cell3 = tableRow.insertCell(3);
      cell3.innerHTML = row['margin percent'];
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Bit of a quick fix, but does the job. Not sure what you needed that `td` (cell) className for though.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all rows that contains a cell with a class **hide-dash** and hide them:

```
var columsHide = customerTable.getElementsByClassName('hide-dash');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(columsHide, function(el) {
            el.parentElement.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the cells given the class: `hide-dash` you can change visibility with css:

```
hide-dash {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This would work if I wanted to hide all rows in that column...however, I only am needing to hide rows where the column equals a dash

Comment: Plus, this would hide a `td`, not a `tr`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the display to none for the whole row. So add the class 'hide-dash' to the row you've created.

```
.hide-dash {
  display: none;
}


<table>
  <tr class='hide-dash'>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fhrpv81a/1/

Update:

Using jQuery you can do this:

$('.hide-dash').parent().hide();

Comment: this wouldnt work because I only have a table template in my HTML...the actual table rows are created by inserting data in my javascript file

Comment: I can't physically add the hide-dash class in my HTML because all I can put there is the table headers and I dont want the class to affect the header. I'm pretty sure it needs to be done through javascript somehow